# IntelliJ IDEA weird foreach-loop warning

Tags: java, arraylist, intellij-idea, foreach

IntelliJ IDEA is giving me a weird "weak warning" in my code where I loop through an `ArrayList`:

[image: Weird warning]

From what I know this is already a `foreach-loop`, so I'm confused why IDEA gives me this warning. I'm assuming that this is a bug, what do you think?

When I click "more" it shows the following text -

> This inspection reports foreach loops which can be replaced with
>   stream api calls. Stream api is not available under Java 1.7 or
>   earlier JVMs.

Comment: Can you post the code as well?  My company's firewall is blocking your image host.

Comment: for (Platform p : platforms) - This loop

Comment: Have you read, what *"more..."* contains?

Comment: @Tom "This inspection reports foreach loops which can be replaced with stream api calls. 
Stream api is not available under Java 1.7 or earlier JVMs."

Comment: Is still something unclear about that message? Since you're not using what IDEA suggests, the message is appropriate.

Comment: Oh. Didn't knew about that new Java 1.8 feature. Is it better to use the new forEach() - loop or  could there be issues with the compatibility to older java versions?

Comment: Well, it is a *Java 1.8.* feature, so what do you think? :P You'll a Java 8 environment to run that application.

Answer (score 4):

IntelliJ IDEA wants to replace the loop with a Java 8 stream api `forEach()` call  (using a lambda). I think that warning is a little unclear, but it's from the *Java | Java language level migration aids | foreach loop can be collapsed with stream api* inspection.

Answer (score 3):

Using Lambda expressions, you can streamline your code.

```
Collection<String> platforms = Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
platforms.add("Platform A");
platforms.add("Platform B");

// Prior to Java 8:
for (String platform : platforms)
    System.out.println(platform);

// With Java 8 Lambda expressions:
platforms.forEach((platform) -> System.out.println(platform));
```